# How to execute ansible-playbook with web interface properly?

Tags: php, ansible

I write playbook with lot of var inside :

example : `ansible-playbook testplaybook.yaml --extra-vars 'city=london username=john'`

I would like to be able to run my playbook dynamically with a form on the web interface (PHP), how can I execute an Ansible playbook with var from a web interface?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [AWX](https://github.com/ansible/awx), it is a web interface and REST API around Ansible, and is supported and maintained by Red hat.

Comment: I have already tested AWX, the product is oversized for my needs I am looking to create something lighter, a simple web page will be sufficient. I just want to find a secure way to use the ansible-playbook binary in a secure way

Comment: @PrintSernoal you could always just call ansible directly from a PHP script. The main challange is how to get it secure and avoid command injection on your server, especially since this will be the server with credentials for all other servers. Specifically for this case your could create a JSON file in a temp directory with all the user passed vars and then pass them into ansible like `ansible-playbook release.yml --extra-vars "@some_file.json"` that way you never have to put user input on the command line directly